# Disable webcam in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser

Firefox has introduced a new "feature" called [Hello](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/hello/), which accesses your webcam and microphone to allow you to start "conversations" with friends.

For obvious reasons, I find it quite disconcerting that my browser should be able to access these devices at will ... anyone know how to disable such access without a hardware modification?

Comment: Mozilla support has your answer: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1043588

Comment: This disables Hello, as far as I can see, but not the webcam/microphone from firefox.

Comment: Programs are allowed to access your hardware. All browsers can access your webcam/microphone. I'm not sure what you're asking, if you're hoping to prevent a single program from accessing shared hardware.

Comment: I was hoping that Firefox had some preference setting that disabled all webcam/microphone access, or maybe there was an extension (like noscript) that required user confirmation before these are accessed.

Comment: As shroeder says, those things wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Firefox does ask you before giving webcam/microphone access to a website, no need to worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind installing additional security software on your computer, then there are some products that will prevent processes on your computer from accessing the webcam and microphone.  I know of two of them - [SpyShelter](https://www.spyshelter.com/spyshelter-premium/) and [Zemana AntiLogger](http://www.zemana.us/product/antilogger/overview/).  Both of those products will detect when a process tries to access your webcam or microphone and prompt you to allow or block it.  You can create rules to have the product remember if it should allow or block each type of access for each process.

Answer (score 2):

honestly, a software solution for such things is just never going to be something I think anyone should trust.

Get a post-it note and stick it over your camera.  I've got had the trimmed corner of one there permanently.  It's reversible, but the level of difficulty for an attacker to defeat it means it can't be-beat for the level of trust it provides compared to the difficulty spent on the solution.

If only there were a solution so simple for microphones - I'd actually be inclined to damage inbuilt mics in my hardware since if I'm likely to use telephony it'll be with a plug-in headset anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As @schroeder said, pretty much any program on your computer has access to all your hardware. You *could* theoretically sandbox Firefox to prevent access to your camera hardware, but it doesn't really make sense to do so. Why do you not trust Firefox with camera access and yet you trust other programs? Is Firefox somehow less worthy of trust? Let's just say you have Adobe Reader installed. From a security standpoint, Adobe Reader also can access your camera and spy on you if it wants to, and there's no logical reason to give it any more trust than Firefox. If anything, it's pretty notorious for security vulnerabilities and also closed-source. Honestly, it would do more good to cover your camera with a post-it and instead focus on keeping your computer free of malware.